# Android: How to monitor WiFi signal strength

Tags: android, networking

I would receive notifications when signal strength changes. I tried to create the following method and call it in the onCreate():

```
private void initializeWiFiListener(){
    Log.i(TAG, "executing initializeWiFiListener");

    String connectivity_context = Context.WIFI_SERVICE;
    final WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService(connectivity_context);

    if(!wifi.isWifiEnabled()){
        if(wifi.getWifiState() != WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLING){
            wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            WifiInfo info = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
            //TODO: implement methods for action handling
        }

    }, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.RSSI_CHANGED_ACTION));
}
```

I would appreciate if anyone could check if the method is written correctly. I tried to run the app, but haven't received any notifications and am not sure whether it is because the signal strength might be constant in the place I run debug or it is because something is missing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, make sure you have `<uses-permission>` for `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` in your manifest.

Second, I'm not sure about notifications for a single connection, but to get notifications of everything the radio is seeing, you can start a scan:

```
wifi.startScan();
```

Next, when I've received successful results, I used `WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION` in the `IntentFilter`.

Then, in the receiver, I use `getScanResults()` from the `WifiManager` object, which also contains the signal strength.

For stopping it this way, you simply call to `unregisterRecever()` (so you'll want to keep it around for referencing). I haven't tested myself to see if my scanning code can be modified to just check the current connection, but I do know I got plenty of results -- Wi-Fi signals change frequently and quickly. I suppose for monitoring a single connection, you can also just filter the scan results and look for the one the device is currently connected to.

I hope this helps a little.

Comment: could you develop your answer a litle bit please?

Answer (score 0):

Just to drop my solution:

in my App I have

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    networkStateReceiver = new NetworkStateReceiver(this);
    this.registerReceiver(networkStateReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"));
    this.registerReceiver(networkStateReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS"));
    networkStateReceiver.registerListener(this);
}
```

And the onReceive in my Receiver looks like:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        switch (networkInfo.getType()) {
            case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_ETHERNET:
                this.networkStateMessage = new NetworkStateMessage(networkInfo);
                break;
            case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI:
                this.networkStateMessage = new NetworkStateMessage(networkInfo, wifiManager.getConnectionInfo());
                worker.schedule(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() { wifiManager.startScan(); }
                }, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                break;
            default:
                this.networkStateMessage = null;
                break;
        }
    }
    notifyStateToAll(this.networkStateMessage);
}
```

The idea is the to `startScan()` only every 5 seconds if the wifi is the active network.