# Android wifi's signal strength

Tags: android, wifi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: How to monitor WiFi signal strength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206891/android-how-to-monitor-wifi-signal-strength)

Is there a way to know the signal strength of a wifi network using code?

Comment: Haha, did you mean *pro*grammatically?

Comment: Looks like this question gives you the procedure for getting WiFi strength: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206891/android-how-to-monitor-wifi-signal-strength

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at these:

```
getScanResults()
level
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html