# How to detect Wifi or GPRS signal strength is strong or weak

Tags: android

I am developing an android application in which I call a webservices. My problem is that if I make a call to the webservice and the wifi or GPRS strength is weak, then my application force close. How can I detect if the wifi or GPRS signal strength is strong or weak?

Comment: What's the point in detecting this? You'd better take a good look at the error and figure out a way to fix/handle it.

Comment: i only want to call webservices if Wifi or GPRS signal strength is strong .if  Wifi or GPRS signal strength is weak,then it will give message"Internet connection is low"

Comment: And what if the signal drops right after you have checked it's strength?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure you have `<uses-permission> for ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` in your manifest.

Second, I'm not sure about notifications for a single connection, but to get notifications of everything the radio is seeing, you can start a scan:

```
wifi.startScan();
```

Next, when I've received successful results, I used `WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION` in the IntentFilter.

Then, in the receiver, I use `getScanResults()` from the WifiManager object, which also contains the signal strength.

For stopping it this way, you simply call to unregisterRecever() (so you'll want to keep it around for referencing). I haven't tested myself to see if my scanning code can be modified to just check the current connection, but I do know I got plenty of results -- Wi-Fi signals change frequently and quickly. I suppose for monitoring a single connection, you can also just filter the scan results and look for the one the device is currently connected to.

I hope this helps a little.

[Android wifi's signal strength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411626/android-wifis-signal-strength)

[Android: How to monitor WiFi signal strength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206891/android-how-to-monitor-wifi-signal-strength)