# find out if an android device has physically moved, not it's location or speed

Tags: android

I spent the last 12 hours investigating the possibilities of doing indoor, small distance navigation based on accelerometer and compass readings. Things aren't looking good, measurement quality is terrible and unreliable.

I was wondering if there is any other method of finding out whether the player (its for a game, or some interactive experience platform) has moved his location a significant amount (> 1m).

I don't need accurate readings (although that would be great), just knowing whether the player is moving or standing still would be a great help. I wouldn't even know where to begin to look for this, and I haven't been able to come up with any brilliant ideas myself.

Comment: Just a thought but you could model a box and map it to points using the camera, eg corners of cupboards/desks etc (anything square). Then each frame you could map the movement of the points to infer a change in location of the camera. This plus gps, plus accelerometer, plus compas could give relatively accurate results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there really isn't a go to solution for small distance calculations on Android.

Some people have mentioned some small success with a few techniques, but they all require having some sort of central point to calculate from and they are still pretty sketchy.

ie.

- Signal strength of a bluetooth signal. [bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149295/android-2-1-how-do-i-poll-the-rssi-value-of-an-existing-bluetooth-connection)
- Signal strength of a wifi signal. [wifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411626/android-wifis-signal-strength)
- Playing a sound from a central point and listening for it from the phones microphone.