# Broadcast receiver with RSSI_CHANGED_ACTION never called

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

BroadcastReceiver doesn't work as expected. Its onReceive() method is not called.

Sample code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WifiManager wifiManager;
    private final WifiStateReceiver wifiStateReceiver = new WifiStateReceiver();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(WifiManager.RSSI_CHANGED_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(wifiStateReceiver, intentFilter);
        wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiManager.startScan();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(wifiStateReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private class WifiStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.v("WifiStateReceiver", "WifiStateReceiver.onReceive() is called. Action: " + intent.getAction());
        }
    }

}
```

Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

All permissions are granted. I tested this code on Android 8 and Android 10.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717741/application-never-receives-rssi-changed-action

Comment: @ande, I saw this question, but that code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this article -  https://link.medium.com/dMNM7lF9zbb and place this code:

```
wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.startScan();
```

inside your method `onReceive()`

This should help

Comment: I tried to put startScan() in onReceive(). It didn't work.