# What is the best way to execute a background process after some specific action?

Tags: android, background-process

I'm writing an android app that connects to a specific WIFI network. The tricky part is that, when the user connects manually to other network, or turns off the WIFI, or the connections lost (because the user walks away)... I need to forget this network (removeNetwork).

My question is the following: How can I do to achieve this?

- Do I need to create a service that runs in the background and every 5 minutes check what is the status of the WIFI?
- Is there any "hook" method to run a class, method, function when the WIFI change of some specific status?
- What is the best way to achieve this problem?

Really thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise you to implement a broadcast receiver in your application that can activate whenever there are any changes in terms of network or wifi connectivity and in the onRecieve()  method of that broadcast receiver you can do any sort of processing whenever the connection is lost.

this goes in your manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".WifiReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and this is the java code.
public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private final String TAG = "WifiReceiver";

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    int wifiState = intent.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN);
    String wifiStateText = "No State";

    switch (wifiState) {
    case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLING:
        wifiStateText = "WIFI_STATE_DISABLING";
        break;
    case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLED:
        wifiStateText = "WIFI_STATE_DISABLED";
        break;
    case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLING:
        wifiStateText = "WIFI_STATE_ENABLING";
        break;
    case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED:
        wifiStateText = "WIFI_STATE_ENABLED";
        break;
    case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN:
        wifiStateText = "WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN";
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    MyLog.d(TAG, "onReceive Broadcast > WiFiState: " + wifiStateText);
    MyLog.d(TAG, "onReceive Broadcast > Time: " + new Date());
}
```

}
and don't forget to add the following permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the following posts on creating a BroadcastReriever that will be called when network state changes:

[Internet listener Android example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12157130/internet-listener-android-example)

[Network listener Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783117/network-listener-android)