# Determining the type and quality of the connectivity on Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi, connectivity

I am trying to understand how to work with the ConnectivityManager, and while I see some good samples [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783117/network-listener-android) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12157130/internet-listener-android-example) as well as on the [Official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html).

I already have a BroadcastReceiver setup and listens to the "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" Intent, but I am still confused about how exactly should I figure out the following pseudo logic:

```
String result = null;
if (WifiConnected)
    result = "Wifi: " + getWifiName();//or ID that can be related to the list of Wifi networks on the device
else if (MobileDataConnected)
{
    String networktype = GetMobileNetworkType();//2G/3G/4G
    String roaming = IsMobileRoaming();//Roam/Home
    result = "Mobile: " + networktype + " " + roaming;
}
else
{
    result = "Not connected";
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: Someone shared a nice gist that might be of some use to you : https://gist.github.com/emil2k/5130324

Comment: Thanks!! Together with CommonsWare's answer, I managed to hack what I needed :-)

Answer (score 1):

[Call `getActiveNetworkInfo()` on `ConnectivityManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getActiveNetworkInfo%28%29). This returns a `NetworkInfo` object that will tell you the [type](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#getType%28%29) (WiFi, mobile data), [sub-type](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#getSubtype%28%29), and [roaming status](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#isRoaming()).

The only thing I am uncertain of is the 2G/3G/4G stuff. I *thought* that was the sub-type, but I may be wrong about that.

Comment: Thanks!! Together with 2Dee's link, I managed to hack what I needed :-)