# Do something when retrieve internet connection (Android)

Tags: android, connection

I want to sync my embedded database with my server when the internet is up again, there is a clean way to do it instead of checking the internet connection with a while(true) in a background thread?

Now I'm checking Internet connetion manually this way:

```
public boolean isOnline() {

    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {

        Process ipProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8");
        int exitValue = ipProcess.waitFor();
        return (exitValue == 0);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
```

I solved follwing this:
[Internet listener Android example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12157130/internet-listener-android-example)

Comment: but this notifies if network is available not internet available right?

Comment: This solved my problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12157130/internet-listener-android-example