# How to get Up time in android device programmatically

Tags: android

I am working on developing a settings kind of application in android where i need to retrieve the details of the device
I am having difficulty in finding the following
Signal Strength,
Service State
and Up time.

How to find these 3 current values?
Where can i get the sample settings application?

[image]

Comment: @Dunken- Thanks , it works. but i want to make it dynamic. Any suggestions on how to do it? If you can please provide me the link of (settings->about phone) activity please.

Comment: Did you find a way to display internet uptime in Kotlin?

Answer (score 17):

Up-time:

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#uptimeMillis()

Service State:

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/ServiceState.html

Signal Strength:

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html#getGsmSignalStrength()

And here's a link to the platform setting:

> https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/src/com/android/settings/deviceinfo/Status.java

Comment: I need the source code of the settings application that is available in the device as in the picture. where can i find that??

Comment: -I need some example code rather than the class information. If you find, pls help. Thanks for the help..

Comment: OK, I added a link to the platform.

Comment: `uptimeMillis` is, most likely, not what you want, you want `elapsedRealtime`. The former isn't counting time in deep-sleep, whereas the latter is doing it.

Comment: @Dunken Platform link does not exist

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onReceive(WifiManager wifiManager) {
                  int numberOfLevels=5;
                  WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
                  int level=WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(wifiInfo.getRssi(), numberOfLevels);
                  System.out.println("Bars =" +level);
            }
```

This may Provide you the Signal Strength there is a refrence Below

[How to get signal strength of connected WiFi android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18831442/how-to-get-signal-strength-of-connected-wifi-android)
May be this will help you

Comment: Thanks. but how to find it if the device if not connected thru wiifi but something else like mobile data?