# Detect WiFi range in android programatically

Tags: android, wifi

I am working on WiFi issue based project. How can I Detect WiFi range in android pragmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not some site where you simply ask some question and you get the answer. Here, you need to specify first what you have tried and what you have failed at! Take a look at these links.

[Monitor WIFI strength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206891/android-how-to-monitor-wifi-signal-strength)
[WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html)
[ScanResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html)

You would get much better answers if you could post what have you already done and tried and what is the issue that you are facing!