# wifi range detection in android

Tags: android, wifi

I am writing an application in Android to notify the user when he reaches in a particular location. There will be wifi hotspots will be available in each places and when user reach in the range of wifi hotspot, then the app will invoke a web service. The application may not be running at that time or it may be in the background I need to do the same. Is it possible?

When I checked, I think I can do it by using broad cast receiver. But can I do it when the app is not running or in background?

One other challenge I am facing is, the android device may be connected to other wifi, then I need to get notification when the user reaches in the range of my wifi hotspots.

Comment: [Possible](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/01/monitor-wifi-status-and-information.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14253424/detect-wifi-range-in-android-programatically